# NoErrorObjectAvailable Script error. when selecting value from picklist in Salesforce LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am trying to show/hide columns based on selected picklist value from **Picklist 3** filter.

**Example:**

Assuming that value is **Type 1**, table should be like this:

[image]

Assuming that value is **Type 2**, table should be like this:

[image]

If **Picklist 3** value is changed to **All**, table should be like this:

[image]

There are no error messages upon saving and deploying codes to the org, but each time I select a **Picklist 3** value, I encounter this message:

[image]

I also inspected browser's developer console for some javascript errors, and I got

> OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

This doesn't make sense to me since I haven't encountered any errors when compiling it via Visual Studio Code.

Meanwhile, here are the current codes I have:

**accountLWC.html**

```
<template>  
    
    <div>
        <lightning-combobox
            class="slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-left_small"
            name="box2"
            label="Picklist 2"
            value={picklist2Value}
            placeholder="--None--"
            options={picklist2Options}
            onchange={findAccountResult} >
        </lightning-combobox>  
        <lightning-combobox
            class="slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-left_small"
            name="box3"
            label="Picklist 3"
            value={picklist3Value}
            placeholder="--None--"
            options={picklist3Options}
            onchange={displayCol}>
        </lightning-combobox>      
    </div>    
    
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="accountPicklist1">Picklist 1</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="accountName">Account Name</div>
                </th>  
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="accountPicklist2">Picklist 2</div>
                </th>  
                <th class="type1" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="type1Header">Type 1</div>
                </th>  
                <th class="type2" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="type2Header">Type 2</div>
                </th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
           
            <template if:true={mapData}>
                <template for:each={mapData} for:item="keyValue">
                    <tr key={keyValue.key} class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div>{keyValue.key}</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="mapValue">
                                <div key={mapValue.Name}>
                                    {mapValue.Name}
                                </div> 
                            </template>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="mapValue2">
                                <div key={mapValue2.Picklist2}>
                                    {mapValue2.Picklist2}
                                </div> 
                            </template>
                        </th>
                        <th class="type1" scope="col">
                            <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="mapValue3">
                                <div key={mapValue3.CustomTextField}>
                                    {mapValue3.CustomTextField}
                                </div> 
                            </template>
                        </th>
                        <th class="type2" scope="col">
                            <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="mapValue3">
                                <div key={mapValue3.CustomTextField}>
                                    {mapValue3.CustomTextField}
                                </div> 
                            </template>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template> 
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
    
    <center>
        <template if:true= {noRecordsFound}>
            --No Account Records Found--
        </template>
    </center>
</template>
```

**accountLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getDataFromApex from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccountData';

export default class accountLWC extends LightningElement {

    @track mapData = [];

    @track noRecordsFound = true;

    @track picklist2Value = '--None--';

    @track picklist3Value = '--None--';

    @track picklist2Options = [
        {value: 'A', label: 'A'},
        {value: 'B', label: 'B'},
        {value: 'C', label: 'C'}
    ];

    @track picklist3Options = [
        {value: 'All', label: 'All'},
        {value: 'Type 1', label: 'Type 1'},
        {value: 'Type 2', label: 'Type 2'}
    ];

    findAccountResult(event) {
        const accPicklist2 = event.target.value;

        if(accPicklist2) {
            getDataFromApex ( {accPicklist2}) 
            .then(result => {
            
                if(result) {
                    for(var key in result) {
                        let tempMapData = [];
                        tempMapData.push({key:key,value:result[key]});
                        this.noRecordsFound = false;
                        
                    }   
                    this.mapData = tempMapData;      
                }
                                 
            })
        } 
        else {
            this.mapData = undefined;
            this.noRecordsFound = true;
        }
    }

    displayCol(event) {
        const picklist3 = event.detail.value;    

        if(picklist3 === 'Type 1') {
            this.template.querySelectorAll(".type1").style.display = "block";
            this.template.querySelectorAll(".type2").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if(picklist3 === 'Type 2') {
            this.template.querySelectorAll(".type1").style.display = "none";
            this.template.querySelectorAll(".type2").style.display = "block";
        else {
            this.template.querySelectorAll(".type1").style.display = "block";
            this.template.querySelectorAll(".type2").style.display = "block";
        }
    }

}
```

**AccountController.cls**

```
public class AccountController{

    @AuraEnabled

    public static Map<String, List<AccountWrapper>> getAccountData(String accPicklist2) 
    {
   
     Map<String, List<AccountWrapper>> mapPicklist1 = new Map<String, List<AccountWrapper>>();
     Map<String, Integer> accPicklist1CountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
     

     List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Name, Picklist1__c, Picklist2__c, Custom_Text_Field__c
            FROM Account 
            WHERE Picklist1__c != null AND Picklist2__c =: accPicklist2 
            ORDER BY Picklist1__c];       
         

     for(Account accObj:accountList)
     {
      List<AccountWrapper> accWrapperList = new List<AccountWrapper>();
      
      if(mapPicklist1.containsKey(accObj.Picklist1__c))
      {
       
       accWrapperList = mapPicklist1.get(accObj.Picklist1__c);
       
       
       accWrapperList.add(new AccountWrapper(accObj));
       
       mapPicklist1.put(accObj.Picklist1__c, accWrapperList);
       
      
       accPicklist1CountMap.put(accObj.Picklist1__c, accWrapperList.size());
      }
      else
      {
       
       accWrapperList.add(new AccountWrapper(accObj));
       mapPicklist1.put(accObj.Picklist1__c, accWrapperList);
       
       
       accPicklist1CountMap.put(accObj.Picklist1__c, accWrapperList.size());
      }
     }
     
     return mapPicklist1;

    }
   
    public Class AccountWrapper {
     
     public AccountWrapper(Account acc)
     {
      this.Name = acc.Name;
      this.Picklist1 = acc.Picklist1__c;
      this.Picklist2 = acc.Picklist2__c;
      this.CustomTextField = acc.Custom_Text_Field__c;
     }
     
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Name {get;set;}
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Picklist1 {get;set;}
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Picklist2 {get;set;}
     @AuraEnabled
     public String CustomTextField {get;set;}
     
    }

    
   }
```

This is the first time I encountered such issue, even refreshing the page does not do anything about it. I hope anyone could help me on this.

Comment: please use `this.template.querySelector(".type1")` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('type1')` using this is not a best practice.

Comment: @rahulgawale thanks for your response! Let me try your suggestion first. But may I know why this `document.getElementsByClassName('type1')` is not best practice at all? Does this have conflict when implemented with Salesforce lwc?

Comment: @rahulgawale I modified the code and replaced previous with `this.template.querySelector(".type1")` but upon clicking a picklist value, columns are not hidden. Also, columns that should be hidden are duplicated.

Comment: the reason you can find [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_dom). Also I just realized that you need all of the components so use `querySelectorAll` so you get the list of all elements.

Comment: @rahulgawale i replaced `querySelector` with `querySelectorAll`, `[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.` displays again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common cause of this error is the null pointer exception. You need to use `event.detail.value` to get the value from the picklist. Also, you don't need to do this `picklist3.value`.

Also, you don't need to set visibility by manipulating the DOM. instead of that create reactive properties to show/hide the elements.

> Setting display style will hide the element but it will leave empty
> space.

Follow the below steps.

**Create reactive properties for the columns.**

```
//...
showType1 = true;
showType2 = true;
//....
```

**Refer them in HTML**

```
<th class="type1" if:true={showType1} scope="col">
    <div class="slds-truncate" title="type1Header">Type 1</div>
</th>  
<th class="type2" if:true={showType2} scope="col">
    <div class="slds-truncate" title="type2Header">Type 2</div>
</th> 
 ...
 ...

<th if:true={showType1} class="type1" scope="col">
    <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="mapValue3">
        <div key={mapValue3.CustomTextField}>
            {mapValue3.CustomTextField}
        </div>
    </template>
</th>
<th if:true={showType2} class="type2" scope="col">
    <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="mapValue3">
        <div key={mapValue3.CustomTextField}>
            {mapValue3.CustomTextField}
        </div>
    </template>
</th>
```

**Change the values based on picklist**

```
displayCol(event) {
    const picklist3 = event.detail.value;
    if (picklist3 === 'Type 1') {
        this.showType1 = true;
        this.showType2 = false;
    } else if (picklist3 === 'Type 2') {
        this.showType1 = false;
        this.showType2 = true;
    } else {
        this.showType1 = true;
        this.showType2 = true;
    }
}
```

[Here is the playgorund](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/TuHwJpB0k/5/edit)

Comment: I modified javascript file based on your answer, but same script error occurs. Code has been updated, please check,

Comment: can you please create a playground with some dummy data? @Ertyq

Comment: Will do. Let me prepare it first, then will let you know immediately. How can I share credentials to you?

Comment: No no just create a public playground [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground), with some hardcoded data. @Ertyq

Comment: Can you try to access the following? [link] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/TuHwJpB0k/3/edit) Apologies as this is my first time using this. Seeing errors when saving js file as well, looks like it doesn't recognize those lines with the `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @Ertyq I have updated the answer, also check the linked playground.

Comment: It's finally working. Wondering why `this.template.querySelectorAll` was accepted on Visual Studio Code, though. Will make use of the playground moving forward for verification just to be sure. But this is much simpler compared to the previous version. Thank you so much again for your help :))

Comment: `this.template.querySelectorAll` works but not suitable for this scenario, also it returns a array of elements